# using instance of in collection

Tags: java, collections

I have to read a binary file. I have to read two type of object "Company" and "Person". Those object are represented by the two classes: Company and Person. Those classes are derived from "User" classes.
When I read this file I have two put the two object "Company" and "Person" into two different HashMap. My professor told me I have to use the keyword `instanceof` but I don't understand how use it.

```
            try
    {
    ObjectInputStream reader=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fname));

        while(reader.available()>0)
        {
            User obj=reader.readObject();
                            if(obj istanceOf Company)
                            ...
                else if(obj istanceOf Person)

                     }



    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ffe)
    {
        System.err.println("Error: the file was not found!");
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

is it right?

Comment: Unrelated to the concrete question, the `available()` method really doesn't do what you think it does... Do not use it. You need to rewrite the `while` condition. Your book/coursesheet should have the proper examples.

Comment: Into this binary file I have a series of object Company and Person.How can i read them until the end of file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
if (obj instanceof Company) {
    Company company = (Company) obj;
    companies.put(someId, company);
} else if (obj instanceof Person) {
    Person person = (Person) obj;
    persons.put(someId, person);
}
```

In the above code, `obj` is the Object you read from the file, assuming that you don't know its type. Also I'm assuming that you have a `Map` of companies called `companies` and a `Map` of persons called `persons`, and in either case you must have some sort of identifier (I'm calling it `someId`) to use as a key for storing the object in the corresponding map.

Answer (score 3):

What I could understand from the question is that the reading logic will have return type User (Parent Class), so in order to figure out what is the actual type of an object, you would have to write following logic,

```
// Assuming fsin is a FileInputStream object



   User obj = getObjectFromFile(fsin);

    if(obj instanceof Company)
    {
       // put obj to Company hashmap

    }
    else if(obj instanceof Person)
    {
       // put obj to Person hashmap

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are talking about serialization, using the classes ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream.

The method readObject() returns an object. To know what kind of object you can use 'instanceof':

```
Object o = ois.readObject();
if (o instanceof Person)
{
     Person p = (Person) o;
     persons.put(p.name, p)
}
// Same for company
```